# What happens if my vanguard cash account is negative?

Tags: australia, vanguard

I have recently opened an account with Vanguard Australia. I have made some investments through a deposit into the cash account and some I have made some through the auto invest option. I am guessing that as I made the investments the market moved before those orders got filled.

When I checked my portfolio today overall it's positive but my cash account is showing -$0.13. While it's a small amount I don't imagine the company likes me owing them money.

Will I get charged an overdraft fee for this?

Should I deposit $1 just to get it positive or should I just leave it as it is until my next auto invest?

Comment: Does your account have a money market or similar cash investment fund? Those are common in the US, where uninvested cash is automatically swept. They often only operate in full shares which are worth exactly one dollar, so there's often cents floating around.

Comment: @user71659 I don't believe so. I'm still new to this so there may be one but not that I am aware of.

Comment: I'd deposit $1, just for safety.  After all... it's just a dollar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just left the account as it was with the negative cash balance until the next deposit cycle. So far I haven't been charged any kind of overdrafting fee. Thanks for the responses but I believe this to be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the policies of the Vanguard Australia, and surely they spell it out in all the paperwork you signed when opening an account. You can probably call their customer service and ask, if you forgot.

Normally what happens is that the money is considered borrowed with the assets of your account as collateral. They may charge you fees or interest and this may depend on the amount.

There may be a limit on how much you can "borrow" in this way. Once you go over the limit, you will likely get a margin call or similar request to add funds to do account. If you fail to do so, they will liquidate (sell) everything in your account, close it, and send you a bill for what's left over. But at only $0.13, you obviously don't have to worry about that.